# second hand ipad needs apple id from original owner?

Tags: ipad, icloud, apple-id

I bought this ipad second handed I already disabled it bt after connecting it to a wiffi its says "This iPad is currently linked to an Apple Id sign in with the Apple ID that was used to set up this ipad" is there anywway i can get pass through that.

Answer (score 0):

Contact the previous owner and have them release this device or get your money back from the seller.

This is an anti theft feature so you won't be able to simply bypass it.